# How to attach wheels to the base of slotted-angle rack?

Tags: design

I want to build some heavy-duty racks with four wheels each as follows. The load is not more than 500 kg. The frame is made of slotted angle iron and the board is about 8mm thick.

[image]

The available wheels are

[image]

What is the easiest way to attach the wheel? There are two kind of wheels here, with a bar that must be inserted to the frame or a flat base wheel.

## Edit

I found from the internet:

[image]

What kind of base plate is it?

Comment: Is this a rack that is made to set on the ground that you want to add wheels to, or are you designing and building the rack from raw materials?  The design of something meant to stay stationary on the ground and one pushed around on wheels will be quite a bit different.

Comment: @JPhi1618: For use in warehouse transporting some items ordered by customers. Designing from raw material.

Comment: I mean are you taking a rack you bought somewhere that is designed to just set on the ground?  What I'm getting at is if the rack was not designed to have wheels, you will probably need to add a base to it.

Comment: @JPhi1618: I have to design from raw materials (slotted angle iron and board). Not from the already erected rack.

Comment: The casters you edited in appear to be the basic plate type, but the blue legs on the cabinet have plates welded to them as an anchoring base. You probably won't have those in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll use one of the variants with the plate on top, and you'll use three of the four slots for carriage bolts. The carriage bolts should have square lugs that fit the size of the slots.

If you find that the corner bolt doesn't have good bearing, or the hole wouldn't be well-positioned with respect to the ends of the metal components, you many need to first install corner plates of heavy steel (1/4" or better). These could be anchored to the bars with four bolts positioned outside the area occupied by the caster plates.

The variants with the pins would require metal bores to properly support them against that load. You'd have to bolt metal blocks into your frame. It's not a good strategy.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for company use and you don't have the experience or knowledge to fulfill "I have to design..." then you may want to consider discussing this with your boss (or boss' boss if need be).

"Not more than 500kg" can still be a *lot* of weight and something goes wrong, you and/or your company could end up on the wrong end of a lawsuit that could be *quite* costly.

I'd **strongly** recommend

- buying a rack, or
- having an accredited engineer sign off on the design

So that liability is in someone else's lap. Bring those points to the boss - bosses don't tend to like opening the company up to law suits.

Of course, if you *are* the engineer/designer who is supposed to have the education/experience/knowledge to be doing this, yet you're turning to strangers on the internet to help with this kind of design...